# XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN - (BORDER_THIN cannot be resolved or is not a field) in poi 4.1.2

Tags: java, apache-poi-4

I have upgraded apache POI from 3.9 to 4.1.2 version. Getting error for XSSF font, styles, hyperlink, cell range address etc., Help me what are the changes required to do for upgrading to this version.

Maven dependency added,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What about reading the `API` documentation? Or the [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)? To the issue in your heading: Formerly `XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN` is now [BorderStyle.THIN](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BorderStyle.html#THIN). See also [DrawingBorders](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DrawingBorders).